# How do I test all of the data structure and ShowAll() methods when I create an instance of that class?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

```html
public class Student{
           
     private String name;   // key field 

     private int ID; 

     private double GPA; 


   public Student(String name, int ID, double GPA){
     
       this.name= name; 
       this.id= ID; 
       this.gpa=GPA; 
   } 

    public void setName(String name){ 
    
     this.name= name; 

   } 

   public String toString() { 
 
      return " Student Name: " + name + " Student ID: " + ID + "Student GPA: " + GPA; 
    }
  
  public String getName() { 

      return name; 

    }

   public void setID(int ID) { 

     this.ID= ID; 
 
    } 

     public int getID(){ 

      return ID; 

    } 

    public void setGPA(double GPA){ 

       this.GPA= GPA; 

    }

   public double getGPA(){ 
 
      return GPA; 

   }

  
}
```

```
public class StudentListings{

     private int next; 

     private int size;

     private StudentListing[] data; 

   public StudentListings(){ 

    next=0; 
    data= new StudentListings[Size]; 
    size= Size; 

   } // end of constructor 

   public boolean insert(StudentListings newStudentListing) { 

     if(next>=size) // the structure is full 
      return false; 

    // store a deep copy of the client's node

     data[next]= new StudentListing.deepCopy(); 

     if(data[next]== null) 
      return false; 
      next= next + 1; // prepare for the next insert 
       return true; 

    } // end of insert method 

   public StudentListings fetch(String targetKey){ 

    StudentListings studentListings; 
    StudentListings temp; 

    // access the node using a sequential search 
     int i=0; 

    while(i < next &&!(data[i].compareTo(targetKey)==0)
    {
        i++; 
    } 

    if(i== next) // node not found
      return null; 

     // deep copy the node's information into the client's node 

     studentListings= data[i].deepCopy(); 

     if(i!= 0) // bubble-up accessed node
     { 
        temp= data[i-1]; 
        data[i-1]=data[i];
        data[i]= temp;
     } 
        return studentListings; 

   } // end of fetch method 


   public boolean delete(String targetKey){ 

    int i=0; 
    while(i < next && !(data[i].compareTo(targetKey)==0))
     { 
        i++; 
     } 
     if(i==next) // node not found

      // move the last node into the deleted node's position
       return false; 
       data[i]= data[next-1]; 
       data[next-1]=null; 
       next= next-1; 
       return true; // node found and deleted

   }  // end of delete method 

   public boolean update(String targetKey, StudentListings newStudentListing){

    if(delete(targetKey)== false) // node not in the structure
      return false; 
    else if(insert(newStudentListing)==false) // insufficient memory 
      return false; 
    else 
       return true; // node found and updated 

   } // end of update method 


   public void showAll(){

    for(int i=0; i< next; i++)
       System.out.println(data[i].toString()); 

  } // end of showAll method 


  public static void main(String[] args){ 

    StudentListings obj1= new StudentListings(); 

   // how do I test each of this methods to see if they actually work?

    obj1.insert(); 
    obj1.fetch(); 
    obj1.delete(); 
    obj1.update(); 
    obj1.showAll(); 

 } 

} // end of StudentListings class
```

I have created a Java program that is designed to keep track of student's names, identification numbers, and GPA's, but I want to know how I can test each one of my methods given the code I have? Can someone help me? Thanks! Here is my code of what I have so far. Also, how will my instance variables come into play at when use my methods. Some of the methods that I have are the insert method, fetch method, delete, and update method.

Comment: some of the functions contain parameters , you need to learn passing parameters in functions and what not

Comment: @ roshan_nazareth Do you think you can help me?

Comment: refer [Tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Comment: @roshan_nazareth But it doesn't help me for my methods?

Comment: This code doesn't compile because it inconsistently uses `StudentListings` in some places and `StudentListing` (no 's') in others. Also, it doesn't make any sense to have `name`, `ID`, and `GPA` on the listings rather than the individual student. This class seems to be intended to represent both individual student data, and a list of students.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed something else. The constructors don't make any sense. You have two constructors that don't take any parameters, and set fields equal to themselves, or, in one case, to a zero-length array. This code won't compile. It doesn't make any sense to ask about how to test code that won't compile, and has serious conceptual and design problems.

Comment: @DavidConrad Conrad How can I fix this then?

Comment: The first thing I would do is break it into a `Student` class, and a `StudentListing` class. Then, test each piece as you go. Create a student. Print the student out. Create a listing, and two students. Add the students to the listing. And so on. Try each piece, making sure you understand it and it works the way you think it should, before moving on to the next piece.

Comment: Also, inside the `StudentListing` I would keep the `Student`s in a `List<Student>` using an `ArrayList<Student>`, unless you're required to use an array and manage the size yourself for this project. Lists are way easier to work with than arrays.

Comment: @DavidConrad What if I just want to keep it in one class like I have it now?

Comment: Then I would just make the class be a `Student` class, and use a `List<Student>` in the main method to maintain the list of students.

Comment: @David Conrad I can't change the name of the class.

Comment: @DavidConrad What would be the easiest way to complete my goal given the code that I have now?

Comment: Well, you have to at least fix the syntax errors, add parameters to the constructors, and then you can run the program to test and see if it does what you expect. You'll have to add the parameters to the method calls, too; for example, `insert` expects a `StudentListings` object as a parameter.

Comment: @David Conrad So for the four operations (insert, delete, fetch, update) what type of parameters would go in those? I was confused about that.

Comment: It's your code, right? Just read the method signatures. `insert` takes a `StudentListings`, `fetch` takes a `String`, `delete` takes a `String`, `update` takes a `String` and a `StudentListings`.

Comment: @David Conrad Yeah, I created the program, but I had help from the textbook I was reading it from.

Comment: @David Conrad So you were saying that I don't need any of the instance variables? But I won't I need them to input into some of the methods?

Comment: I was saying that the instance variables need to be split up into ones related to students, and ones for student listings, but you don't want to split them up. You do need to add parameters to the constructors, though, otherwise how are the instance variables ever going to get set?

Comment: @David Conrad Okay so it's possible to complete my end goal of testing the methods? I just have to add parameters into the constructor and methods? But when will the instance variables come into play at?

Comment: Have you ever written a class with a constructor?? You pass a parameter to the constructor. You assign the parameter to the instance variable. You need to read the introductory lessons on classes in the Java tutorial.

Comment: @DavidConrad I know that, but I was thinking that they would also come into play for some of the other methods too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I understand your question to be "How do I get started testing?  Tutorials aren't helping me."  I think there is a step to start before you go through the code in the tutorials.  This is something some good books will show you but fits into an answer here so giving it to you here.

When you write tests, you are testing that the behaviour is as it was designed, which means you should start by having designed behaviour.  My recommendation is that you go through the following processes:

1. Document (via javadoc comments) your class and all methods.  Document parameters, outputs, and side effects.  "This is what this is supposed to do."  Unless you know what it is supposed to do you have nothing to test.
2. In a separate document, write up a list of corner cases, areas that you want to support, but are afraid might break as the code changes.
3. Then go pick up jUnit tutorials and write your tests for the corner cases you wrote up in step 2, making sure behaviour is as documented in step 1.

Comment: there is so much wrong in the OP code before trying any cases

Comment: @Chris Travers Do you think you can help?

Comment: @roshan_nazareth, but people have to start somewhere.  Hence my recommendation to start with design documentation.  As I say, documentation, design, and testing are quite a bit harder than coding.

Comment: @dorakta, you need to start by thinking through your design.  Until you do this you don't have anything to test.  After all, if correct behaviour is defined as current behaviour than all code is bug free, right?  There are tons of things which are obviously wrong in your code.  But you need to figure out what you want the code to do before you can define the tests to fix the problems.

Comment: @Chris Travers-I have decided to create two classes, but I confused about StudentLisitng  class. Do I keep some of the same methods as the initial code of the StudentListing or what areas of code I need to fix and get rid of? Do you think you provide some pseudocode for me as to what methods and variables should be placed in the StudentListing class, please?

Comment: @David Conrad Can you answer my question?

Comment: @doraka, frankly this is the pencil and paper stage.  Write up both options as classes.  Forget the implementation, just do the class/method declarations and javadocs in terms of what the input is, what the output is, and what guarantees you are willing to make.  Design *and testing* issues become a lot easier when you start by documenting what behaviour you want to advertise to users of your class.